# AS3 DispatchedEvent not being heard by listener

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hey so i have had a look at some other posts but im still not getting anywhere.

I have 2 classes, one is Ticket_mc() and the other is TicketPurchaserFSlider(). there is a number stored in TicketPurchaserFSlider() called ticketsSelected which holds the number of tickets i have selected. Now what i want to do is to be able to increment that number by one from the Ticket_mc() class. and how i set that up was to create an dispatchEvent(new Event("selectFromList")), and then a listener and a function conected to that listener. anway its not working. Here is my code:

```
    package com.spay.ticketpurchaser {

    import com.spay.ticketpurchaser.TicketPurchaserFSlider;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;


    public class Ticket_mc extends MovieClip{
        public function Ticket_mc(){
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickTicket);
        }

        public function clickTicket(event:MouseEvent){
            dispatchEvent(new Event("selectFromList"));
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
    package com.spay.ticketpurchaser{

    import com.spay.ticketpurchaser.Ticket_mc;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;    

    public class TicketPurchaserFSlider extends MovieClip{

        public var ticketsSelected:Number = 0;
        private var ticket:Ticket_mc;

        public function TicketPurchaserFSlider(){           
            ticket = new Ticket_mc();
            ticket.addEventListener("selectFromList",addTicket , false,0,true);
            }

        private function addTicket(event:Event){
            ticket.removeEventListener("selectFromList", addTicket);
            ticketsSelected ++;
            trace("it works");
        }
   }
}
```

For clarification, here is the scenerio

I have a ticketPurchaserFSlider class that holds my ticketsSelected var. I have other methods inside the TicketPurchaserFSlider class that increments and decrements the ticketsSelected var and it all works just fine, i then use the document class to addChild(ticketPurchaser) and so on.

I then needed the tickets, and these tickets needed to also be clickable and also increment and decrement the ticketsSelected var in the ticketPurchaserFSlider class. To display the tickets i first create the Ticket_mc and exported for actionsctript. I then created an empty MovieClip and gave it a class called Ticket_Group, this class holds an Array that created 6 instances of the tickets. I then created another empty movieclip and created another class and called it Ticket_Batch, this also holds an Array and creates more instances of tickets (in multiples of 6) the number of tickets it is creating is stored in ticketPurchaserFSlider class and is called maxTickets. i access this number by using the an instance of the ticketPurchaserFSlider and using the . syntax ( ticketPurchaser.maxTickets) i then use an instance of the Ticket_Batch class in the Document class to addChild(tickets), so i have all of my tickets displays from the document class.

now im not sure if this was the best way to display the tickets, but it made logical sense to me and the tickets will be singlely selected and selecable by multiples of 6 (using a seperate button) and in both cases i need to be able to access the ticketsSelected var in the ticketPurchaserFSlider class.

It fires off okay from the clickTicket function.

I hope that has cleared things up. If you think i need a better way of setting up my classes then do say so.

I have posted the files here: www.samuelpay.com/BingoClient.zip so take a look if you want too.

Comment: It looks like you've set the `bubbles` parameter in `dispatchEvent` (second one) to `false` by not setting a value. If the class listening is a parent of the class dispatching, you need to have `bubbles` set to `true`.

Comment: @user655480, you shouldn't post additional information as an answer, so I put it in your original question for you.

Comment: hey sorry for posting in wrong place :(... ill check out the dispatch event

Answer (score 0):

Mouse event listeners called only if their target are in display list. You need to add ticket in display list:

```
ticket = new Ticket_mc();
ticket.addEventListener("selectFromList",addTicket , false,0,true);
addChild(ticket);
```

Comment: The ticket itself is in the display list in another class. The Ticket_Batch class uses an Array to create multiple instances of the Ticket_mc class. Would this be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Put a trace inside this function of yours:

```
public function clickTicket(event:MouseEvent){
    dispatchEvent(new Event("selectFromList"));
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Let us know if it fires, i.e. if the mouse click is being handled. Then we'll know more about where the problem lies.

Cheers,
Timo

Answer (score 0):

Yes it sounds like you have a problem with instances here, you must listen for event on the particular instance. One solution might be to pass the array of the Ticket_mc instances to TicketPurchaserFSlider so you can add the event listeners for each instance. An other, probably better way, is to let Ticket_Batch listen for clicks and then redispatch to TicketPurchaserFSlider.

Comment: How would i go about passing the array to TicketPurchaserFSlider? i have tried to create an instance of the Ticket_Batch class in my TicketPurchaserFSlider class and it comes up with an Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred. this has really got me stumped, if i had it all in one class it would obviously work, but thats just not he AS3 way is it?

Comment: Stack overflow means that you probably have stacked function calls, e.g. a function x that calls a function y that calls function x. In your case it might be that you instantiate TicketPurchaserFSlider in your Ticket_Batch and then you make a instance of Ticket_Batch in TicketPurchaserFSlider. That will create a loop which makes flash throw a stack overflow. If you want to pass the array to TicketPurchaserFSlider I suggest you can pass it in the constructor. See code in my answer post.

Comment: okay this is a bit of a nooby question to ask but so how do i create an instance of the TicketPurchaerFSlider class within the main.as class (the class that displays everything) as the parameters complicate things a little more and i have never used the type :Vector, and probs need to look into using parameters too (currently researching)

Comment: You can use Array instead (I've changed the code, check it out). You instantiate like this `_ticketPurchaer = new TicketPurchaerFSlider(_tickets);` where _tickets is your array of Ticket_mc's.

Comment: Ahh yes a Vector is the same as an Array its just everything has to be of the same type. Right so its an Array. Now i am still having a problem. I have my main class which puts everything in the display list. Now when i am trying to create an instance of my ticketPurchaserFSlider class in my main.as class it is saying: 1120: Access of undefined property _tickets. thatnks alot for the help so far.

Comment: Well, you need to declare _tickets, or instead pass the array of tickets (if you already have one)

Comment: e.g `private var _tickets:Array = [];` And then fill _tickets with you ticket instances, e.g. `_tickets = [nameofticketinstance1,nameofticketinstance2, nameofticketinstancen];` Or if you have lots of them or create them dynamically you will need to fill the array in a better manner like a loop or on creation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it (code not tested, might be typos):

```
package com.spay.ticketpurchaser
{

    import com.spay.ticketpurchaser.Ticket_mc;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;    

    public class TicketPurchaserFSlider extends MovieClip
    {

        //public var ticketsSelected:Number = 0;
        //private var ticket:Ticket_mc;
        private var _tickets:Array;

        public function TicketPurchaserFSlider(tickets:Array)
        {     
            _tickets = tickets;  
            setUpTicketListeners();  
            //ticket = new Ticket_mc();
            //ticket.addEventListener("selectFromList",addTicket , false,0,true);
            }

        private function setUpTicketListeners():void
        {
           for(var i:int = 0; i<_tickets.length; i++)
           {
               _tickets[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTicketClick);
           }
        }       

        private function onTicketClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
           var currentTicket:Ticket_mc = Ticket_mc(event.currentTarget);
           //do your stuff
        }

        //private function addTicket(event:Event)
        //{
           // ticket.removeEventListener("selectFromList", addTicket);
           // ticketsSelected ++;
           // trace("it works");
        //}
   }
}
```